# Oracle Data Modeler - How to Commit DDL changes back to Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

Initial Note: Created Model by choosing to `Import` the `Data Dictionary` using one of my Connections and then choosing the `Schema` and lastly the `Tables` for which I want to model.

After making changes within Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler how can I commit the changes made in the newly created relational model back to the database.

I can manually parse thru the generated DDL but that seems like unnecessary work.  I attempted to use the 'Synchronize with Data Dictionary' option however when I went back to my tables within my schema they were not altered/updated in any way.  No Primary Keys... Foreign Keys, Indexes or any other of the DDL actions I created in the model were seen in my database.  What am I missing here?

[image]

I really thought the Synchronize options where what I should be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will never commit changes to the database.

You'll do the compare, review the delta DDL, and then if you think it's good - load it up in SQLcl, SQL Developer, or SQLPlus to run.

It's not that we don't trust you to do the review part first, but also, it'd be just too easy to muck up a database if you hit the wrong button. Especially as some table structural changes could result in data loss.

Comment: And so that would suggest that the `Synchronize` options are there to do exactly what you said... allow me to review.  Basically... it's my job to determine what DDL should be run (in my DB) whether it is ALL of it or just portions of it.  Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: yes, you can review the differences, and hit the 'check' box saying you approve, then when you generate the DDL, those items are included in your script. Which you then go and run yourself...outside of the modeler